# Laravel: Using OR in multiple Where Claus

Tags: laravel

Converting SQL to Laravel format is still a bit confusing for me. I need to use OR. If onloan = NULL OR 0 then display record.

The code below can only detect the 0 but not the NULL.

```php
    public function finditembarcode () {

        if ($finditembarcode = \Request::get('q')) {
            $itembarcode = Item::where(Item::raw("BINARY `itembarcode`"), $finditembarcode)
                ->where('onloan','=', NULL OR 0)
                ->paginate();
        }else{
            $itembarcode = ''; //If nothing found, don't return anything.
        }

        return $itembarcode;
    }
```

I also tried but get the same result as code above.

```php
->where('onloan','=', NULL || 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel [Database Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses) **whereNull / whereNotNull / orWhereNull / orWhereNotNull**

```
->where('onloan', 0)->orWhereNull('onloan')
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried your code but it displays all records that are NULL. I tried whereNull as well.